# Redis Credis_Client Php library

Tags: php, redis

I am using Php Credis_Client library for one of my application. It has defined all the redis commands in similar methods.

Though calling these functions storing and retrieving data well from Redis.

I went through the library code to check what exactly it does. However I am unable to figure out how it works?

Here is the code:

The function which i am using to set hash key,

```
hSet('test','field','value');
```

and this is what i see in Redis lib file

```
 * Hashes:
 * @method bool|int      hSet(string $key, string $field, string $value)
 * @method bool          hSetNx(string $key, string $field, string $value)
```

and in the __call($name, $args) function

```
$response = call_user_func_array(array($this->redis, $name), $args);
//where $name can be function name and $args is parameters to be passed
```

However not able to figure out where hSet function is written in php.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `__call()` method is a fallback for non-explicit defined method in a class: it is called when you try to use a class method that doesn't exist.

IE:

```
cass A {
   public function x1() { return 1; }
   public function x2() { return 2; }
   public function __call($name, $args) { return 3; }
}

$a = new A;

var_dump($a->nonExistingMethod(1,2,3));
```

this shows 3.

the `__call` method also receive 2 parameters, the first one is the name of the non-existing function you invoked, and the second is an array of parameters,

in the previous example, `$name` wold be `nonExistingMethod` while `$args` would be an `array( 1, 2, 3 )`.

In your case, when you call `hSet` it fallsback to the __call method using `'hset'` as name and `array('field','value')` as parameter, resulting in `$this->redis->hSet('field','value')`

Comment: Thanks for the help .But if it is non existing method then how does it wirte data in redis?

Comment: chech what kind of object `$this->redis` is, and it should have either a `hset` or `__call` method as well

Comment: Yes it is using phpredis - Redis class for calling all these  functions. which are defined in that class. but how it is calling redis class. As Credis_Client has only one file.